# vba GetCursorPos User-defined type not defined error

Tags: vba, types, powerpoint, defined, user-defined

I'm making label1 move with the mouse in powerpoint.
But I get User-defined type not defined error.

code:

```
Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Type POINTAPI
 left As Long
 top As Long
End Type

Dim Xoff, Yoff As Long
Dim dragstate As Boolean
Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
dragstate = True
Xoff = X
Yoff = Y
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
If dragstate = True Then
 With Label1
  Dim mouse As POINTAPI
  GetCursorPos mouse
  .top = mouse.top / 2 - Xoff
  .left = mouse.left / 2 - Yoff
 End With
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
dragstate = False
ActivePresentation.SlidesShowWindows.View.GotoSlide ActivePresentation.SlidesShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrhAo.png)
can someone help me?

Comment: Do you work in a 32 bit application? If not, try `Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long`.

Comment: i'm work in 32 bit

Comment: Try `Dim Xoff As Long, Yoff As Long`. Otherwise,  `Xoff` is declared `As Variant`.

Comment: Replace every instance of .SlidesShowWindows with .SlideShowWindow and replace Label1 with With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Label1") or some other way of referencing the Label1 shape.

Comment: ok..i will try it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're putting that code in Slide1. In this case, you need to declare the user-defined type with Private.

Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Private Type POINTAPI
left As Long
top As Long
End Type

Or you need to move the user-defined type declaration to the standard module.